# How to make bootstrap datetimepicker in table(in modal) show when the content behind has a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datetimepicker

I am unable to get my bootstrap datetimepicker to show properly in this table. I can tell the scrollbar in the table behind is the culprit any work around?Datetime Picker Position Image

[image: Datetime Picker Position Image]

This is the JS function where I put the widget positioning:

```
$(function () {
        $('#datetimepickerCreationDate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
            widgetPositioning: {
                horizontal: 'left',
                vertical: 'bottom'
            }
        });
    });
```

And I've placed the td cell position to relative:

```
<style>
.table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > th{
 position: relative !important;
 border-top: none !important;
}<style>
```

This is the modal markup with the datetimepicker:

```
<div id="FilterModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateFilterModal" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Filter Settings</h4>
                    </div>
                    <%-- modal-header--%>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <table id="tblFilterSettings" runat="server" class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Property
                                    </th>
                                    <th>Operator
                                    </th>
                                    <th>Value
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Contractor Name
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboContractorNameOperator" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ToolTip="Contractor Name Operator">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="=">Equals</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="like">Contains</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtContractorNameValue" class="form-control" runat="server" title="Contractor Name Value">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Contract Number
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboContractNumberOperator" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboContractNumberOperator_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                            AutoPostBack="true" ToolTip="Contract Number Operator">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="=">Equals</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="<">Less Than</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="<=">Less Than or Equal</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value=">">Greater Than</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value=">=">Greater Than or Equal</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="Between">Between</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </br>
                                        <label id="lblContractNumberAnd" runat="server" visible="false">AND</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtContractNumberValue" class="form-control" runat="server" title="Contract Number Value">
                                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvtxtContractNumberValue" runat="server" ForeColor="red"
                                            ControlToValidate="txtContractNumberValue" Display="None" ClientValidationFunction="CheckNumericalAmount"
                                            ErrorMessage="Only numerical characters greater than 0 allowed." ValidationGroup="PageValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
                                        <ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender_cvtxtContractNumberValue" runat="server"
                                            TargetControlID="cvtxtContractNumberValue">
                                        </ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                                        <br />
                                        <input id="txtContractNumberValueAnd" class="form-control" runat="server" visible="false" title="Contract Number Value">
                                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvtxtContractNumberValueAnd" runat="server" ForeColor="red"
                                            ControlToValidate="txtContractNumberValueAnd" Display="None" ClientValidationFunction="CheckNumericalAmount"
                                            ErrorMessage="Only numerical characters greater than 0 allowed." ValidationGroup="PageValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
                                        <ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender_cvtxtContractNumberValueAnd" runat="server"
                                            TargetControlID="cvtxtContractNumberValueAnd">
                                        </ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Creation Date
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCreationDateOperator" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboCreationDateOperator_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                            AutoPostBack="true" ToolTip="Creation Date Operator">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="=">Equals</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="<">Less Than</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="<=">Less Than or equal</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value=">">Greater Than</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value=">=">Greater Than or equal</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="Between">Between</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </br>
                                        <label id="lblCreationDateAnd" runat="server" visible="false">AND</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td >
                                        <div class='input-group date pull-right' id='datetimepickerCreationDate'>
                                        <input class="form-control" runat="server" id="txtCreationDate" tabindex="7" title="Contract Creation Date" data-date-format="DD-MMM-YYYY"
                                            onkeydown="return false" type="text">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepickerCreationDateAnd' visible="false" runat="server">
                                            <input class="form-control" runat="server" id="txtCreationDateAnd" tabindex="8" title="Contract Creation Date" data-date-format="DD-MMM-YYYY" 
                                                onkeydown="return false">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Contract Type</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboContractTypeOperator" runat="server" ToolTip="Contract Type Operator" CssClass="form-control">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="=">Equals</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="like '%' +">Contains</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtContractTypeValue" runat="server" title="Contract Type Value" class="form-control" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Contract Status</td>
                                    <td>Equals
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboContractStatus" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Style="display: inline;">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="All">All</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Open</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="4">Closed</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="5">Rejected</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Pending Approval</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSaveFilterSettings" causesvalidation="true" validationgroup="PageValidate">Save</button>
            </div>
            <%--modal footer--%>
        </div>
        <%--modal-content--%>
    </div>
    <%--modal-lg--%>
</div>
<%-- Filter Modal--%>
```

Comment: give css `z-index` to the calendar table.

Comment: @Raviteja i tried, I added this to the stylesheet    .datepicker-days  > table {
            z-index: 1151!important;
        } but it shows the same way.